# Get world position of plane

Tags: three.js

I'm very new to three.js so I'm sure I'm miss-understanding something here.

I've created a plane in the following way:

```
var planeGeom = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(0.2, 0.2);
planeGeom.rotateX(-Math.PI / 2);
var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffff00, side: THREE.DoubleSide}));
plane.position.set(0, 0.1, 0);
scene.add(plane);

var mathPlane = new THREE.Plane();
planePointA.copy(plane.geometry.vertices[plane.geometry.faces[0].a]);
planePointB.copy(plane.geometry.vertices[plane.geometry.faces[0].b]);
planePointC.copy(plane.geometry.vertices[plane.geometry.faces[0].c]);
plane.localToWorld(planePointA);
plane.localToWorld(planePointB);
plane.localToWorld(planePointC);
mathPlane.setFromCoplanarPoints(planePointA, planePointB, planePointC);

var helper = new THREE.PlaneHelper( mathPlane, 1, 0xffff00 );
scene.add( helper );
```

Why is my PlaneGeometry object and Plane positioned differently? Why doesn't .localToWorld() get the world position of the plane?

https://jsfiddle.net/sek0yzLp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.updateMatrixWorld()` on the `plane` after setting its position:

```
plane.position.set(0, 0.1, 0);
plane.updateMatrixWorld();
scene.add(plane);
```

Comment: Thank you. I spent the whole of yesterday trying to work this out, and in one line of code everything is working now! =)